# Can I hard code data for a KendoScheduler DataSource?

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am attempting to debug a KendoScheduler application, and I would like to use some hard coded data instead of an ajax call.

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
... other code...
```

Instead of supplying a url to a service, is there any way to use a string or json object or something local?

Answer (score 4):

Local array example from [doc](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler/configuration/datasource)

```
<div id="scheduler"></div>
<script>
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
  date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
  dataSource: [
    {
      id: 1,
      start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
      end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
      title: "Interview"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
      end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
      title: "Meeting"
    }
  ]
});
</script>
```